# Why inherit property is not working in the following case?

Tags: css, css-transforms

```
<div class="box outer">
        <div class="box inner">box-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box outer">
        <div class="box inner box-2">box-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box outer">
        <div class="box inner">box-3</div>
    </div>
```

/* If I use position property */

```
.box {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 2px solid purple;
    }
    
    .outer {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .inner {
        background-color: brown;
        transform: scale(0.75) rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .box-2 {
        position: relative;
        left: 100px;
    }
```

The browser shows me my expected result
[image: using position property]

/* If I use transform property for .box-2*/

```
.box-2 {
     transform: translateX(100px);
        }
```

the browser shows(not expected):
[image: using transform property without inherit]

/* if I use inherit property */

```
.box-2 {
            transform: translateX(100px) inherit;
        }
```

[image: using inherit property with translateX()]

the transform property isn't inherited(not expected) Here is my problem.

/* If I write the code as follows */

```
.box-2 {
            transform: translateX(100px) scale(0.75) rotate(45deg);
        }
```

Then the browser shows the expected result as the same as using position:relative; and left:100px;
[image: expected result]

So my question is why inherit property isn't working or what's wrong with my codes???

Answer (score 0):

When doing this:

> `.box-2 {transform: translateX(100px);}`

You will simply override the previous transformation set on inner since only one transformation can be set:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.outer {
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
  background-color: brown;
  transform: scale(0.75) rotate(45deg); /* this will have no effect */
}

.box-2 {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box outer">
  <div class="box inner">box-1</div>
</div>
<div class="box outer">
  <div class="box inner box-2">box-2</div>
</div>
<div class="box outer">
  <div class="box inner">box-3</div>
</div>
```

[image]

When doing this:

> `.box-2 {transform: translateX(100px) inherit;}`

This value is simply invalid. You cannot combine `inherit` with something else. `inherit` is a value on its own. So your browser will simply ignore it and the initial transformation is used

[image]

---

As you already found, the correct way is to chain all the transformation:

```
transform: translateX(100px) scale(0.75) rotate(45deg);
```